# How to set multiple return paths with java mail?

Tags: jakarta-mail

I need to set multiple `return path` emails. This is important in case of an undeliverable email . I need more than one person to be notified

This is how I set one

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.put("mail.smtp.from", "bouncebackemail@example.com");
```

How to set multiple "bounce back emails" (or return paths)  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to specify multiple return path addresses.

You could set the return path to be an "alias" that forwards to multiple recipients.